# Calling external API with Angular 6 in production

Tags: angular, rest, heroku, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to call a Flask API that's on Heroku, from an angular web app also hosted on Heroku.  I'm able to do it locally with a **proxy.conf.json** file.

How do I do it when both the API and web app are production? Both on Heroku servers.

In my **service**, I tried to call the entire URL instead:

```
getCars() {
    return this.http.get<Car[]>('https://bbd-api.herokuapp.com/api/car');
}
```

That doesn't work.

**Home Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CarsService, Car } from '../cars.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  cars: Car[];

  constructor(
    public carService: CarsService
  ) { 
    this.getCars();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  getCars(){
    this.carService.getCars().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.cars = data;
      },
      error => {
        alert("Could not retrieve a list of cars");
      }
    )
  };

}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface Car {
  color: string;
  make: string;
  model: string;
  year: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CarsService {

  constructor(
    public http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getCars() {
    return this.http.get<Car[]>('https://bbd-api.herokuapp.com/api/car');
  }
}
```

Any suggestions? Can't get it to work on Heroku production servers.